# cakephp find the array elements by meeting the conditions between two arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have two arrays. One array consists of *Id* & another array consists of the values & keys. For example. I have a variable called *Fruit_id*, which consists of:

```
array(
    'fruit_id' => array(
        (int) 0 => '3',
        (int) 1 => '4'
    )
)
```

and another array called *fruits*, which consists of:

```
array(
    'values' => array(
        (int) 1 => ' Apple',
        (int) 2 => 'Banana',
        (int) 3 => 'Orange',
        (int) 4 => 'Mango'
    ),
    'keys' => array(
        (int) 0 => (int) 1,
        (int) 1 => (int) 2,
        (int) 2 => (int) 3,
        (int) 3 => (int) 4
    )
)
```

So, based on *fruit_id*, I want to have *Orange* & *Mango* stored in a variable. How can this be achieved?

Comment: what is the use of 'keys' in second array?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about the associations of `values` and `keys` with `fruit_id`

Comment: the values and keys have been derived by requestAction in a json format & it have been decode. the fruit _id consists of id which are the key of the variable fruits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my understanding you can try below code

```
$fruits = array();

foreach ($array1['fruit_id'] as $key1 => $value1)
{
    foreach ($array2['values'] as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        if ($value1 == $key2)
        {
            $fruits[$value1] = $value2;
        }
    }
}

print_r($fruits);
```

This will return **Array ( [3] => Orange [4] => Mango )**

Let me know if this helps you out or any changes needed

Comment: thank you so much. it totally worked out. thanks again.

Comment: welcome, consider voting-up the answer and mark it as correct .

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this easily without even using any loop. Use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) instead.

```
$array1 = array("fruit_id" => array(3, 4));

$array2 = array(
    "values" => array(1 => "Apple",2 => "Banana",3 => "Orange", 4 => "Mango"),
    "keys" => array(1,2,3,4)
);

/* Filter elements from $array2['values'] whose keys are present in $array1['fruit_id'] */

$result = array_filter($array2['values'], function($v, $k) use ($array1){
    return in_array($k, $array1['fruit_id']);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

echo implode(' & ', $result);  // Convert array to string separated by '&'
```